# ubuntu 12.10 gcalctool simple mode only

Tags: gcalctool

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 and gnome 3, I opened gcalctool and there is no way to change the base and the calc type. Am I right or it's just my stupidity?

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to change the mode from menu?

Comment: there is no menu

Comment: I am using GNOME Shell 3.6.2

Comment: It shouldn't help much, but still... In Unity, you do not see the menu attached with the calculator itself. Its present at the top. See the screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X5CfS.png Is it same with Gnome - Do you manage to find the menu bar?

Comment: It is not the same with Gnome, each application holds its menu

Comment: I will switch to Unity and see if there is something there

Comment: @Aditya I was completely wrong: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4i199.png

Comment: @Aditya can you please make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the Calculator mode through the menu. You do not see the menu attached with the calculator itself, its present at the top panel. See the screenshot:

[image: calculator-menu]

To change the base, you would need to use the Programming mode:

[image: change-base]

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the calculator, then left click on the icon of the calculator in the upper left hand corner of the tool bar. A drop down menu will appear where you can select the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only way that I managed to solve that problem was changing the key `Exec` in `/usr/share/applications/gcalctool.desktop` from

```
Exec:gcalctool
```

to

```
Exec:gksu gcalctool
```

There is a nasty consequence: you have to enter the root password every time that you want to open the calculator.